# Meaning of と言って and だ in a sentence from a book

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I am reading the book 鵺の家 by 廣嶋玲子, and I have a question about the usage of the words と言って and だ in the following.

> だが、昨日、兄はこういった。もう逃げることはない。富を見つけたのだ。我々はこの土地でいきていくぞ。皆は喜び、その富とやらのことを詳しく聞きたがった。だが、若き棟梁は**それはまた改めて話すと言って**、決して口を割らなかった。そして今日になって、そっと妹に耳打ちしてきたのだ。森の中で見つけた富を、おまえに最初に見せてやろうと。兄の気持ち**だ**と、少女は喜んだ。

My attempt at translation:

> However, yesterday the older brother said the following. There shall be no more running. For I have discovered a treasure. We will be living in this land. Everyone (in the family) rejoiced and wanted to hear about that treasure. But the young head of the family (the older brother) **while repeating what he said**, did not disclose any details at all. And today he whispered in secret into the ear of his younger sister. He said, I will first show the treasure, which I discovered in the middle of the forest, to you. The girl was glad **that he felt that way**.

I am not sure about と言って。In the last sentence why is there だ? Could we replace だ with に or 見ると? What about 言って。Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

> 若き棟梁はそれはまた改めて話すと言って、決して口を割らなかった

To me it sounds like "the young leader said that he would talk that another time but never confessed". Like "**said** XXX **and** never confessed". And that is probably why he talked to the sister **first**. Like a secret.

と言って can mean adversity sometimes.

> 兄の気持ちだと、少女は喜んだ

To me, that と is the content particle. だ seems to be there because "she was glad that her older brother's feeling **was** that": telling her.